# make custom spreadsheets with python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with two columns:

`year experience` and `salary`

I want to save a csv file with these two columns and also have some stats at the head of the file as in the image:

[image]

Is there any option to handle these with pandas or any other library of do I have to make a script to write it line adding the commas between fields?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas does not support what you want to do here. The problem is that your format is no valid csv. The [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) for CSV states that *Each record is located on a separate line*, implying that a line corresponds to a record, with an optional header line. Your format adds the average and max values, which do not correspond to records.

As I see it, you have three paths to go from here: i. You create two separate data frames and map them to csv files (super precise would be 3), one with your records, one with the additional values. ii. Write your data frame to csv first, then open that file and insert the your additional values at the top. iii. If your goal is an import into excel, however, @gefero 's suggestion is the right hint: try using the [xslxwriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) package do directly write to cells in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file as two separate parts (stats and csv)

Reading stats:

```
number_of_stats_rows = 3
stats = pandas.read_csv(file_path, nrows=number_of_stats_rows, header=None).fillna('')
```

Reading remaining file:

```
other_data = pandas.read_csv(file_path, skiprows=number_of_stats_rows).fillna('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [xslxwriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/.). Perhaps it´s what you are looking for.